# Permalinks - Archives

Tags: permalinks, archives

The WordPress docs say:

```
WordPress offers you the ability to create a custom URL structure for your permalinks and archives.
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen

I see how this screen will result in permalinks for specific posts / pages but I don't see any additional details on this Settings screen on how it will create links for Archived posts/pages.

Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this section](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen#Customize_Permalink_Structure) (excerpt):

- **Day and name** - An example of the day and name based structure is **http://www.sample.com/2008/03/31/sample-post/**

- **Month and name** - An example of the month and name based structure is **http://www.sample.com/2008/03/sample-post/**

- **Numeric** - An example of the numeric structure is **http://www.sample.com/archives/123**

Those are archives-- specifically the first two are "date" archives. That is what the Codex is referring to. See ["Using Permalinks"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) for more detail.

Comment: I can see how if you use `/<some dates>/%postname%/` then when you choose a URL without `/%postname%/` it will create a date Archive. But if I choose just `/%postname%/`, how would this create links to an Archive?

Comment: Play around with it and you will see that both the single post and the archive links are effected. There isn't a way, via that control panel, to isolate the two. They are interconnected.